# Sequence Convergence: $(a^n + b^n)^\frac1n \rightarrow b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm working on this problem but can't find an insight about how to proceed.

The statement: Let $0 \lt a \le b$ and $(x_n) = (a^n + b^n)^\frac1n$ then $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n) = b$

In an example in the textbook prove that $ (c^\frac1n) \rightarrow 1$ using the expression $c^\frac1n = 1 + d_n$ where $d_n \gt 0$ and then the *Bernoulli inequality* but does not explain well why there there is $d_n$.

Any hint will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I come up with this regarding $2^\frac1nb$:

Fixing $\epsilon \gt 0$ that  $2^\frac1nb \lt b + \epsilon$ then $2 \lt (1 + \frac{\epsilon}b)^n$. By Bernoulli inequality we have $(1 + \frac{\epsilon}b)^n \ge 1 + n\frac{\epsilon}b$. We have that $1 < n\frac{\epsilon}b$ when $n \gt \frac{b}{\epsilon}$. Finally for $n \gt N = [\frac{b}{\epsilon}]$ it follows $2 < 1 + n\frac{\epsilon}{b} \le (1 + \frac{\epsilon}{b})^n$ thus $2^\frac1nb \lt b + \epsilon$. Thank you all for your hints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:**   Use that

$$b^n \leq a^n + b^n \leq 2b^n.$$

Comment: Cheers.  We can just consider your hint more sophisticated :)

Comment: Awesome, but it seems like it should be $b^n \lt a^n + b^n \le 2b^n$ as $a^n \gt 0$, right?

Comment: What I said is true, though strictly speaking, you are correct.  Just be careful in taking limits as it is tempting to say that $b < \lim \leq b$, which is incorrect!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

First note that $x_n > b$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ (Why?).

Now show that $b$ is the greatest lower bound for the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

To be more specific, show that given any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$, we have $a^n + b^n < (b+\epsilon)^n$.

For instance, choose $N = \left \lceil \frac{a}{\epsilon} \right \rceil$ and expand by binomial theorem to argue out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to work on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you factor $b^n$ from the expression in parentheses, you can apply the Bernoulli inequality to the remaining expression and get the result you're hoping for.