# Sequence of the form $ a_n^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I came across a sequence of the form $|4^n + (-3)^n|^{1/n}$ and was unsure where to start in terms of computing its limit. Is there a general way to approach sequences of this form with $1/n$ in the exponent? Without brute force computation.

Comment: Have you tried using logarithms? Usually, logarithms + some inequality bashing helps with finding the limits of these kinds of sequences.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/484451/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/777377/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/923219/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73834/42969

Comment: Also this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3084056/42969 and the linked questions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$\bigg|4^n + (-3)^n\bigg|^{1/n} = \bigg|4^n\left(1 + \dfrac{(-3)^n}{4^n}\right)\bigg|^{1/n} = 4\cdot \bigg|1 + \dfrac{(-3)^n}{4^n}\bigg|^{1/n}$$